# How to hide and show progress bar when fetching data from network?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am using the `Context` Api with `Hooks` in my `ReactNative` App.

Here is my code to fetch array of blogs from the api

```
const getBlogPosts = dispatch => {
  return async () => {
    try {
      const response = await jsonServer.get("/blogposts");
      dispatch({ type: "get_blogposts", payload: response.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "get_blogposts",
        payload: "Something went wrong"
      });
    }
  };
};

const blogReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "get_blogposts":
      return action.payload;
     .....
```

Here my Component file I am doing something like below

```
const IndexScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state, getBlogPosts } = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogPosts();

  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList..../>
      {state.length === 0 ? <ProgressBar /> : null}
```

Suppose there are no blogs then the progress bar keeps showing even after the network operation is finished so I can't write the above code for showing and displaying the progress bar
Now I tried firing multiple dispatch when user calls `getBlogPosts` but that changes the value of state from boolean to array and then again to boolean.

Is there an easy way to handle the visibility of progress bar?

Comment: Were do you set length??

Comment: @Idan It is an array of blogposts

Comment: Yet, from your question it is not clear what is state. I think that this part will help people/you answer your question. Maybe try and log the print and see what comes back. The answers are based on assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a new type in the dispatch like `get_blogposts_in_progress` and set `true/false` in the reducer like `state.loading = true` if the dispatch is `get_blogposts_in_progress` and dispatch `state.loading = false` when the api call is a success or an error.

```
const getBlogPosts = dispatch => {
  return async () => {
    dispatch({ type: "get_blogposts_in_progress" });
    try {
      const response = await jsonServer.get("/blogposts");
      dispatch({ type: "get_blogposts", payload: response.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "get_blogposts",
        payload: "Something went wrong"
      });
    }
  };
};
const blogReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "get_blogposts_in_progress":
      return { ...state, ...{ loading: true } };
    case "get_blogposts":
      return { ...action.payload, ...{ loading: false } };
     .....
```

And the component file.

```
const IndexScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state, getBlogPosts } = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogPosts();

  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList..../>
      {state.loading ? <ProgressBar /> : null}
```

Comment: The line return { ...action.payload, ...{ loading: false } }; does not render my list as you have added loading parameter to the array

Comment: try `{ ...state, ...action.payload, ...{ loading: false } };`

Answer (score 3):

Since your blog array can be empty, your blog array may the same after loading. You will have to store a boolean value indicating that the loading is done in your state.

Once your data is fetched, just set this value to `false` :

```
const IndexScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state, getBlogPosts } = useContext(Context);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(async () => {
    await getBlogPosts();
    setLoading(false)
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList..../>
      {loading && <ProgressBar />}
```

You will also have to make your effect `async` to be able to use `await`.

I also used an inline `if` (`&&`) to render the loading component.

Comment: Actually  I have thought about this but I don't want to use this way and instead make use of Reducer. Thank you for your answer

Comment: this caused issues for me, and I had ot wrap wrap the `async` function in a non-async function: `useEffect( ()=>{ (async ()=>{ //do stuff } )() })`